# Gas oven seems to be working, except for smell of gas and occasional in-oven flare

Tags: gas, oven

I have a new gas oven (bought it new ~4 months ago), a Frigidaire FGGS3065PBA. While baking for long periods, a smell of gas will begin to permeate the kitchen. During this time there were sudden bangs from inside of the oven, which I had originally assumed was the sound of metal expanding, but the other night I watched it more closely and noticed that there would be an in-oven flare up where the interior of the oven briefly fills with gas flame.

This happens in both bake and convection modes. We haven't used the broil mode yet.

I've removed the lower plate that covers the lower gas burner to observe its behavior. It seemed to be normal. The igniter comes on and the burner lights up with what appears to be an even flame on either side.

Confusingly, when observing it during this time I did not note a smell of gas. I did only run it for one heat and reheat cycle, for maybe about 5-10 minutes.

At this point I'm stumped. The flare ups are quite concerning and even caused some parchment paper in a recent bake to ignite, and they are scaring my wife. We've called the gas company but they only checked the connection in the back and confirmed that it was connected well and not leaking there.

I could really use some help on this.

Comment: Can you get access to a combustible gas "sniffer" type of detector?  I suspect you may have a leak into the burner compartment...either that, or the burner is flaming out briefly without getting picked up by the flame sensor and shutting the gas down safely, but then getting hard-reignited by the ignitor.

Comment: It is probably the gas jets need to be changed to propane or vice versa. There is an answer already about that on SE somewhere... We had a similar problem, the jets where installed for natural gas and we had propane. Smell was terrible, but it took a while to get real bad.

Comment: Vented? Downdraft?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I'm still collecting data. The gas smell seems to eminate from the vents at the top of the oven door, where a breeze can be felt.
I am certain that the stove is configured correctly for the natural gas that feeds it. There was a propane adapter that came with the oven, but we are on natural gas so I did not connect it. We had the gas company come out and check it, and they verified that the oven was connected correctly. As well, the top burners work just fine.

Comment: Another observation, the gas smell returned after replacing the bottom plate in the oven, which covers the bottom burner. It's a metal plate with a wide W shape, with a small bevel in the middle where the burner lies. I wonder if its presence is affecting whether some of the gas vents ignite.

Answer (score 1):

You either have a leak, or an air mixing tube is not aligned with the gas orifice feeding the venturi, or the orifice is wrong for your gas (or gas pressure).  check the alignment of all of the air-gas mixing venturi's.  Also make sure you have the right orifice for the type of fuel.  Also check the gas pressure.  If you have a malfunctioning pressure regulator, the orifice may be intermittantly getting the wrong pressure, and thus be intermittently delivering the wrong mix to the burner.  Check the pressure both while the oven is running, and when it is off.  If pressure rises when off, the regulator is leaking in the needle valve, if pressure fluxuates or is too high when it is running, there is some other mechanical problem with the regulator.

Comment: Thank you and apologies for taking so long to get back to you. We don't use the oven often so it is easy to forget about it. I will try some of the diagnostic steps you suggest and see what happens.

Comment: We eventually called another repairman to come and take a look at it and he found that the broiler igniter was not functioning correctly. He replaced it and we're good to go now. It doesn't make much sense to me but I'm glad it is fixed.